# Show that $f(x)+f(y) \leq g(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I need to show that $f(x)+f(y) \leq g(x,y)$ if $x \neq y$, where $g(x,y)=1/|x-y|$ and
$$f(x) = 2-2|2x-1|.$$
I have demonstrated the inequality in te following cases: $ y<-x$ or $y>2-x$ or $y>1+x$ or $y<-1+x$. In that cases we have that $f(x)+f(y) \leq 0$.

[image]

But I am stuck in show it in the general case. Any assistance in showing this would be appreciated.

Comment: For $x\geq \frac{1}{2}$, $2x-1\geq 0$, so you can remove the absolute function. For $x\lt y$, $x-y\lt 0$, meaning $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{y-x}$. Have you started working with this?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\ne y,$ let $d=|x-y|.$ Then $d>0$ so  $$g(x,y)-f(x)-f(y)=-4+\frac 1 d +2\cdot(|2x-1|+|1-2y|)\ge$$ $$\ge  -4+\frac 1 d +2\cdot |(2x-1)+(1-2y)|=$$ $$=-4+\frac 1 d +2\cdot |2x-2y|=$$ $$=-4+\frac 1 d +4d=$$ $$=\left(2\sqrt d -\sqrt {1/d}\;\right)^2\ge 0.$$

Comment: I had not seen this appearing while writing an answer, I think we roughly had the same idea (lower triangle inequality, ...)

Comment: @MartinR. That happens to me  a  lot. At least one other answer appeared here as I was typing too.

Answer (score 3):

With the substitution $x=u+1/2$, $y=v+1/2$, the inequality becomes
$$
 4 - 4|u| - 4 |v| \le \frac{1}{|u-v|}
$$
or
$$
 |u-v| \bigl(1-|u|-|v|\bigr) \le \frac 14
$$
and that is true because
$$
|u-v| \bigl(1-|u|-|v|\bigr) \underset{(1)}{\le} |u-v| \bigl(1-|u-v|\bigr) \underset{(2)}{\le} \frac 14 \, .
$$
$(1)$ holds because of the triangle inequality, and $(2)$ holds because $x(1-x) \le 1/4$ for all real numbers $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all cases. WLOG you can assume $y\lt x$, so $g(x,y)=1/(x-y)$. If $y>1/2$, then $x>1/2$ and $f(x)=4-4x$, $f(y)=4-4y$, so $f(x)+f(y)=8-4x-4y$, and you need to prove that $8-4x-4y\le 1/(x-y)$ or $8(x-y)\le 4(x^2-y^2)+1$. Dividing by $4$, we get $2x-2y\le x^2-y^2+1/4$ or $0\le (x^2-2x)-y^2+2y+1/4$ or $(x-1)^2-(y-1)^2+1/4\ge 0$ which is true since $y<x$.

If $y\le 1/2$ and $x\ge 1/2$, we have $f(x)=4-4x, f(y)=4y-4$ and you need to prove that $4y-4x\le 1/(x-y)$ which is true since $x>y$.

Finally if $y<1/2, x<1/2$  then $f(x)+f(y)=4x+4y-8<0$, and again $f(x)+f(y)<1/(x-y)$ because $x>y$.

Comment: Thank you! Why we know that $(x-1)^2-(y-1) ^2+1/4\geq 0$ in the first case?

Comment: Just add and subtract 1 to the LHS of the prev. inequality.